# glDrawArrays() is slow for many points in GTK 3.0?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, gtk3

I would like to ask you about help with function glDrawArrays for draw many points from lidar sensor through GTK 3.0 library. I am using GtkGLArea for visualization. The limit number of points is about 10^6 points. It is quite fine,but 10^7 points in render loop lasts about 0.5 sec. etc. At the start with library GLFW and it was without problem for huge amount of drawed points. Set up of my glBuffers and shaders is same, but GLFW is ingredibly faster. My goal is implement my point cloud directly to GTK 3.0. Does anyne have experiance with this problem?

my shaders:

```
const GLchar  *vertex_src =
"#version 330 core\n"
"layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
"layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColor;\n"
"out vec3 ourColor;\n"
"uniform mat4 model;\n"
"uniform mat4 view;\n"
"uniform mat4 projection;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
   "gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);\n"
    "ourColor = aColor;\n"  
"};\n";

const GLchar *fragment_src =
"#version 330 core\n"
"out vec4 FragColor;\n"
"in vec3 ourColor;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
   "FragColor = vec4(ourColor, 1.0f);\n"
"};\n";

//realize signal from GTK 3.0:
realize
{
  glGenVertexArrays (1, &vao);
  glBindVertexArray (vao);
  glGenBuffers (1, &buffer);
  glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(zasobnikGL[0])*n_body,zasobnikGL,GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  glVertexAttribPointer (0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray (0);
  glVertexAttribPointer (1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
  glEnableVertexAttribArray (1);
  glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
  glBindVertexArray(0);
}

draw ()
{
  glUseProgram (program);
  vec3 position = vec3(0,0,1000);
  vec3 up = vec3(0,1,0);
  mat4 projection = ortho((float)(WIDTH)*(-1),(float)(WIDTH),(float)(HEIGHT)*(-1),(float)HEIGHT, -3000.0f, 3000.0f);
  glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(program, "projection"), 1, GL_FALSE, &projection[0][0]);
  mat4 view = lookAt(position, position + front, up);
  glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(program, "view"), 1, GL_FALSE, &view[0][0]);
  glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(program, "model"), 1, GL_FALSE, &model[0][0]);
  glBindVertexArray(position_buffer); 
  glPointSize(2.0f);
  glDrawArrays (GL_POINTS, 0, n_body);
  glBindVertexArray(0);
  glUseProgram (0);

}
```

Comment: `projection * view * model` could be pre-computed. Other than that, does Gtk accidentally use software rendering by any chance?

Comment: I use gtk_gl_area_queue_render() function in mouse position callback for redraw gl area...